# Перенести текст с чужого сайта на свой

Tags: php, html

На чужом сайте есть блок

```
<div class="text">Содержимое</div>
```

Могу ли я как-нибудь автоматически выводить на свой сайт текст "Содержимое" с этого блока?
Текст взят для примера, какой текст будет в определенный момент - неизвестно.

Comment: можно например сделать так ctrl+c потом ctrl+v в нужном месте.

Comment: Нет. Текст постоянно меняется, мне нужно делать 
это автоматически.

Comment: не заметил этих нюансов в вопросе.

Comment: Извиняюсь, уточнил.

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать парсер страницы чужого сайта, может даже на php, и уже из "спарсенной" страницы достать необходимую информацию и вставить на сайт, но такой способ немного неэффективный в плане производительности. можно так же чтобы парсинг был на стороне клиента, на javascript, но в таком случае могут быть проблемы, если ресурс заблокирован у пользователя. по вопросу парсинга в интернете очень много информации, найти ее труда не составит.